# Decipher the content

Tags: wordplay, english

Around mid-seventies, early eighties this was a popular kid's verbal puzzle.

***Half Circle Full Circle Half Circle Triangle with two legs minus Half Circle Full Circle Right Angle Triangle with two legs***

What was it about ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is clearly:

> COCA-COLA
>  The riddle is describing the shapes of the letters, assuming that an uppercase sans serif font has been used which has a semicircle for the letter C